# Orthocenter of triangle $DEF$ is same as the circumcenter of triangle $ABC$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

$D,E,F$ are mid points of the sides of the triangle $ABC$,then prove that the orthocenter of triangle DEF is same as the circumcenter of triangle ABC.

I cannnot figure out what coordinates to suppose for A,B,C.I tried taking $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$ but calculations go messy and clumsy.Can someone help me in proving this question?

Comment: @Théophile,Oh sir,thanks for notifying,that was a typo!

Comment: What are you allowed to assume in your proof? Can you use the fact that the circumcenter is at the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the sides? Can you use the fact that the line through the midpoints of two sides of a triangle is parallel to the third side? Those two facts combined make the proof easy: just use a diagram and look at those perpendicular bisectors of $\triangle ABC$ and how they interact with the vertices and sides of $\triangle DEF$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algebra isn't necessary. Instead, use geometrical definitions: in particular, the circumcentre $O$ of $ABC$ is at the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of $AB$, $AC$, and $BC$. Do you see how to continue from there?

Comment: Does that mean that perpendicular bisector of BC will be perpendicular to EF,perpendicular bisector of AC will be perpendicular to DF,perpendicular bisector of AB will be perpendicular to DE.

Comment: @Brahmagupta Yes, exactly. The perpendicular bisector of $BC$ will be perpendicular to $EF$, and furthermore passes through $D$ (because $D$ is by definition the midpoint of $BC$). In other words, the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ coincides with the altitude of $D$ in $DEF$. (And the same holds, of course, for the other sides.)

Comment: @Brahmagupta Incidentally, if you did want to approach this algebraically, I would recommend assuming without loss of generality that one point of $ABC$ is at the origin and a second point is on the $x$-axis: $A = (0,0), B = (x_2,0), C = (x_3,y_3)$. That would simplify the calculations. But algebra should really be a last resort in questions like this; not only can the algebraic approach be cumbersome, but you also miss out on what's fundamentally happening in terms of the geometry. As a rule of thumb, start by drawing a diagram and then reflect on the definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a $\triangle ABC$ with side BC coinciding with the x-axis such that vertex B is at origin $(0, 0)$ & vertex C is at $(a, 0)$ then vertex A will be at $\left(\frac{a\tan C}{\tan B+\tan C}, \frac{a\tan B\tan C}{\tan B+\tan C}\right)$. The mid-points $D, E$ & $F$ of the sides $BC$, $AC$ & $AB$ respectively of $\triangle ABC$ are calculated as follows $$D\equiv\left(\frac{0+a}{2}, \frac{0+0}{2}\right)\equiv\left(\frac{a}{2}, 0\right)$$ 
$$E\equiv\left(\frac{\frac{a\tan C}{\tan B+\tan C}+a}{2}, \frac{\frac{a\tan B\tan C}{\tan B+\tan C}+0}{2}\right)\equiv\left(\frac{a(\tan B+2\tan C)}{2(\tan B+\tan C)},\frac{a\tan B\tan C}{2(\tan B+\tan C)}\right)$$
$$F\equiv\left(\frac{\frac{a\tan C}{\tan B+\tan C}+0}{2}, \frac{\frac{a\tan B\tan C}{\tan B+\tan C}+0}{2}\right)\equiv\left(\frac{a\tan C}{2(\tan B+\tan C)},\frac{a\tan B\tan C}{2(\tan B+\tan C)}\right)$$  Hence, the ortho-center $H$ of $\triangle DEF$ is determined as follows 
Now, the orthocenter H can be calculated by finding intersection point of any two altitude equations. We can get orthocenter as  $$H\equiv\left(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{a(\tan B\tan C-1)}{2(\tan B+\tan C)} \right)$$

& the circumscribed center say $P$ can be calculated as $$P\equiv\left(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{a(\tan B\tan C-1)}{2(\tan B+\tan C)} \right)$$ Hence, we can find that orthocenter (H) of $\triangle ABC$ will coincide with the circumcenter (P) of $\triangle ABC$ i.e. both H & P are same.

Answer (score 1):

The circumcenter of the triangle $ABC$ is the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of its sides, i.e. perpendiculars through $D, E, F$. Now, if you join the middle points of the sides you obtain a similar triangle to the original one with its sides parallel to those of the original.
The orthocenter of $DEF$ is the intersection of its altitudes. From the picture you can see that the altitudes of $DEF$ coincide with the perpendicular bisectors of the sides of $ABC$
[image]